# URL rewriting in ASP.NET Core MVC won't use back referencing correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, asp.net-core-mvc

This is a continuation from [Parameter binding to either route or querystring in ASP.NET MVC Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66072486/parameter-binding-to-either-route-or-querystring-in-asp-net-mvc-core/66073008?noredirect=1#comment116818874_66073008). I have an ASP.NET MVC web site in .NET Core 3.1, and I am trying to URL rewrites to put query string values into the path instead, for example `/api/Values?id=1`. I have downloaded the sample application from https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/url-rewriting/samples/ and added my own rule to the `IISUrlRewrite.xml` file, like so:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
      <rule name="my rule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^api/(\w+)$" />
          <condition>
              <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="id=([0-9]+)" />
          </condition>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="api/{R:1}/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
      </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

However, when I run the application and go to `/api/Values?id=1`, the rewritten URL is `/api/Values/?id=1`. So we can see that the rule was applied, and `{R:1}` (the back-reference from the path) was properly applied, but `{C:1}`, which should be the ID number, is instead the entire query string value.

So I tried changing the rule to be like this:

```
      <rule name="some other rule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^api/(\w+)$" />
          <condition>
              <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="id=1" />
          </condition>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="api/{R:1}/1" appendQueryString="false"/>
      </rule>
```

Doing this made it so that the rewritten URL was `api/Values/1?id=1`. So it appears that even though the `appendQueryString` attribute is set to `false`, the entire query string is still being appended.
[image: screenshot of problem]

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the source codes, it seems this is build-in feature, the asp.net core appendquerystring attribute is not as same as IIS's, it will append the new querystring instead of removing it.

The [source codes](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Middleware/Rewrite/src/UrlActions/RedirectAction.cs) is like this:

```
        if (pattern.IndexOf(Uri.SchemeDelimiter, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0)
        {
            string scheme;
            HostString host;
            PathString path;
            QueryString query;
            FragmentString fragment;
            UriHelper.FromAbsolute(pattern, out scheme, out host, out path, out query, out fragment);

            if (query.HasValue)
            {
                if (QueryStringAppend)
                {
                    request.QueryString = request.QueryString.Add(query);
                }
                else
                {
                    request.QueryString = query;
                }
            }
            else if (QueryStringDelete)
            {
                request.QueryString = QueryString.Empty;
            }

            request.Scheme = scheme;
            request.Host = host;
            request.Path = path;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It turns out that this is a known issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/5.0/iis-urlrewrite-middleware-query-strings-are-preserved